# How to execute a command in a Firefox Add-On?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am quite new to writing Firefox Add-Ons, still, I got to a point where I patched together a working extension, except the very core of it.

At some point in the code, I need to execute a system-command on a file. I've found a snipped on the web and tried to adapt it, but without luck. From my `xpi/components/script.js`:

```
var cmd = '/usr/bin/somecommand'

var args = ['-option', 'value', f.path ];

var execFile = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);

execFile.initWithPath(cmd);

if (execFile.exists()) {
    process.init(execFile);
    process.run(false, args, args.length);
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong here? I've assembled the command and I've got the filename but I can't get Firefox to execute this code snippet.

Is this `execFile`, `initWithPath`, `createInstance`, etc. stuff really needed?? I just want to execute the command just like in the CLI:

```
$ somecommand -option value filename
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't execute, do you get an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me with `cmd` and `args` changed to:

```
var cmd = '/usr/bin/say';
var args = ['hello', 'world' ];
```

As Neil says, we need more info for troubleshooting. Enable the [Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console) and check if there are any messages there.